# Do i need to create one more new SSL pushnotification certification for new version of app?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I have an application already running on apple store, and this application has the feature of getting push notification. I am going to release a new version.

For this new version, do i have to create one more new `SSL pushnotification certificate` and a `p12` file or old `ssl` and `p12` used for old version is good enough to make it work?

Is there any changes I need to do or just increasing version number of the app and archiving will be good to go?

As i am uploading new version first time, I am not pretty sure about the step need to be followed. So it would be great if anyone can give me good link to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

As far as my knowledge no need to create the new SSL certificates if you are using the same AppId .

Comment: thanks ernaidu. i am using same Appid, are there any further steps that i need to care off before uploading?

Comment: No need to take care of any other things @RockanRoll .

Answer (score 1):

The provisioning profile only cares about your app id and your certificate. Your certificate only cares about your identification. There is nothing related to to your app version. So there is no certificate and provisioning profile issues to worry about.