# APNS certificates clarification

Tags: ios, ssl-certificate, apple-push-notifications

I was debugging an application that had already been submitted to the App Store. The application uses push notifications. By now i'm done with bugs and i'm going to submit the new version of this app. The problem was that i didn't have distribution certificate so i had to create my own (by requesting a certificate from certificate authority) in order to create AppStore provisioning profile. The question is - will this version of the app support push notifications? Should i sign it with APNS certificate used for previous version or it's not mandatory and i can use my own certificate i have just created?

Comment: go ahead, i dont think that your updated code will affect to push notification unless and until you have the pem file to your server

Comment: i don't have pem file

Comment: @AndreyChernukha if you not have .pem file then create it. And place this where your server files are placed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this version of app you have to adopt each and every step which you have taken for first version of the application. Follow these steps :-

Create new `Certificate Authority` , provision profile and `SSL` and enable the push notification service of this ssl.

Make a `.PEM` and put it on your server (where `Push Notification` server files are placed).

Now sign your app with this new profile.

In simple words follow all steps which you have done for version first. Hope this Helps You !

Comment: Hey, buddy, seems like your answer is not true. When i started to create new APNS certificate in the developer account there are two options available: APNS certificate and AppStore certificate. so they are two different things and it means that i have to use AppStore certificate to create provisioning profile.

Comment: hey man , there is no any term like APNS certificate. You have to choose it for distribution SSL certificate for the purpose of uploading app on app store.

Comment: please read it before futher processing http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Comment: can you please explain me one thing? when i create a certificate for push notification - it's needed just for server side, yes? i don't use it anywhere else, right?

Comment: and also it seems like i don't have to setup push notifications for the second time. take a look at this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268024/do-i-need-to-create-one-more-new-ssl-pushnotification-certification-for-new-vers

Comment: Yes, you not need to setup new push notification "IF YOU HAVE YOUR FIRST VERSION DISTRIBUTION CERTIFICATE". But as you explained in your question you not have it, so you have to create new one. And if this time you have new distribaution certificate then you have to setup .PEM again in push notification server.

Comment: In Simple means you have that account with same appid then you can download that distribution certificate & use it. Otherwise you have to step forward towards New one creation.

Answer (score 3):

1. Get the csr file from keychan access->Certificate Assistant->Request a certificate From Certificate Authority
2. submit the csr file while creating the distribution apns certificate
3. install that cer file and get the p12 file by using export in keychain access
4. now you have the cer and p12 file, and now you can generate the pem file by using following commands

   a) openssl x509 -in aps_development.cer -inform der -out PushChatCert.pem

   b) openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out PushChatKey.pem -in Certificates.p12

   c) cat PushChatCert.pem PushChatKey.pem > ck.pem
5. Now you can send the pem file with your passhrase(i.e generated from above cmds) to your server
6. php code is also here for testing

   ```
   // Put your device token here (without spaces):
   //itouch 4 inch device token for development environment
   $deviceToken = '<device_token_without_spaces>';

   // Put your private key's passphrase here:
   $passphrase = '<your pass phrase>';


   // Put your alert message here:
   $message = 'My first push notification!';

   ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

   $ctx = stream_context_create();

   stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');

   stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

   //development
   //$ios_url = 'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195';

   //production(i.e distribution apns)
   $ios_url = 'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195';


   // Open a connection to the APNS server
   $fp = stream_socket_client(
       $ios_url, $err,
       $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

   if (!$fp)
       exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

   echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

   // Create the payload body
   $body['aps'] = array(
       'alert' => $message,
       'sound' => 'default'
       );

   // Encode the payload as JSON
   $payload = json_encode($body);

   // Build the binary notification
   $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

   // Send it to the server
   $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

   if (!$result)
       echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
   else
       echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

   // Close the connection to the server
   fclose($fp);
   ```